List used as a queue in .net and retain order
I want to use a List as a queue. This is because List is more flexible when getting/inserting data.
My question is when I use Linq operations (DistinctBy, Take) as shown below, do I still get the elements in order they have been added into the list?
private List<IMessage> _queue = new List<IMessage>();

// add many
 _queue.Add(tagMessage);


 toConsume = _queue
     .Where(t => !_snLockList.Contains(t.Id))
     .DistinctBy(t => t.Id)
     .Take(freeTasks).ToList();


Does the title of the question has any relevance with what is asked inside? You are basically asking about the behavior of the LINQ operators Where, DistinctBy, Take and ToList, whether they preserve the order of the source sequence or not. It doesn't matter if the source is a list, a queue, or whatever other collection.

If you only add elements at the end of the list (using .Add() or .AddRange(), the added elements (less those that are later removed) will remain in the order added. If you insert any elements at a specific index using .Insert() or .InsertRange(), they will remain in the same position relative to the elements before and after.  Be aware that List<> is implemented using an array under the covers, so insert and remove operations at other than the end of the list can be costly, as it involves moving elements around in the array.

Without an order by or a skip the LINQ will take the distinct items where they're not in the _snLockList list. I don't understand why you wouldn't just Console/Debug.Writeline() and see for yourself testing a few scenarios?

I ran a lot of multi-threaded operations and the list is working like a queue. Just want to see if under stress or any special cases this behavior will be violated when  Where, DistinctBy, Take operators are used.

@mamen yes, very interesting, but there is no clear conclusion on DistinctBy. I am ok with 'found first' order, but not with an unpredictable order.

List is not thread-safe(!) - it neither requires stress nor special cases for your implementation to go up in smoke. Have a look at thread-safe implementations of IList before worrying about particular LINQ-operations

LINQ treats everything as an IEnumerable<T> the results will depend on the implementation of the relevant enumerator. In practice, that will almost always lead to items output in the same order as they are input unless the operation specifically requires re/disordering. That said, unless it is specifically documented, this is just a result of convenience rather than necessity and there's no guarantee that that won't change in future. Again, though, it's unlikely to ever change in practice. That said, if you specifically require an order then you should implement that yourself.

Note that many LINQ methods have overloads that take the item and its index as arguments. You could start by calling Select and creating anonymous objects that include the item and its index and then finish with an OrderBy that orders by the index and then a Select that extracts the item.

Actually, that last suggestion probably wouldn't work. The indexes that LINQ provides probably just follow the order of the enumeration, whether or not that follows the order of the original list. If everything is an IEnumerable<T>, there's no guarantee that there is any way to get the original index or even if there is one, e.g. in a Dictionary. You could test5 that by creating a custom collection type that deliberately enumerated out of order, but I don't think I'll be spending the time to do that.

@Patola This is because List is more flexible when getting/inserting data. guess what both List and Queue use for storage: T[]. They have the same threading restrictions. ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentStack are thread-safe and use very little (if any) locking. There's no ConcurrentList

This seems like something you can try extremely easily? You already have the code and you presumably have the input data. Why have you not run this code yourself to see whether the answer is 'yes' or 'no'?

The name toConsume is an indicator that you might want to remove some elements from the list, not just select some elements. At least that's how producer-consumer systems usually work. If you want to remove efficiently multiple elements from a list, and be in control of the order of the removed elements, you might find this question interesting (a starting point for a custom RemoveMany implementation).

The answer is "Yes but...".
Yes all LINQ operations that iterate over collections using "foreach, yield return pattern" return results in the order of the underlying object's (your List<T>'s) IEnumerable (see MS Doc - yield, also follow link in this article to iterators) - unless/until another operation reorders (Sort()).
But you do not give enough insight into the "what, how and why" of what you are doing... (1) Lists can be used to implement pretty efficient (ring) queues ("ring buffers" - for which you will probably have to code iterator/s). (2) If you intend inserting into and deleting from the middle of the queue, then you must use (O(n), i.e. pretty expensive) shuffle-up and -down logic (behind the scenes of Insert(), RemoveAt()... and your queue isn't FIFO i.e. isn't really a queue).
Have you considered using PriorityQueue<T> or LinkedList<T>?

I use  _queue.Add(tagMessage);, _queue.Insert(index, tagMessage); and then the above linq operation to select a few items and later I remove them   _queue.RemoveAll(t => toConsume.Any(x => x.QueueId == t.QueueId));. These are the operations I use. I want the list to keep the index order. It's not a strict queue. All operations are done under a lock because of multi-threaded access.

I see the question has been closed (duplication on the LINQ-query-ordering aspect). If the queue can get large and/or performance is important (and/or you are OCD about design like me;-) then from your description I'd seriously consider LinkedList<T> with a policy of "add at the tail and consume first available from the head/front". The benefit being O(1) insertion and removal operations at the (probably very much smaller) cost of some memory fragmentation (.NET's memory management is superb). (Possibly also trading away some of the tidiness and terseness of LINQ.)
